# Three.js + QR scan

Tags: three.js, textures, qr-code, augmented-reality

I am trying to implement a QR scanner from my camera using [jsQR](https://github.com/cozmo/jsQR) which requires a Uint8Array data. [This framebuffer example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_framebuffer_texture) creates a DataTexture which is pretty close to what I want, but I want the added step of accessing the Uint8Array from the DataTexture object so I can feed it into jsQR. How can I do this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you have your camera frame as an image, can you just draw it to a canvas, and then use canvas.getImageData()

Here's some rough code I found on SO...

```
var context = canvas.getContext('2d')
var idata = context.getImageData(0, 0, 64,64);
var data=idata.data;
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(idata.data.length);
var binary = new Uint8Array(buffer);
for (var i=0; i<binary.length; i++) {
    binary[i] = data[i];
}
```